# Adding contents to my wordpress site

Tags: posts

So I am new to blogging and I would like to publish articles written by me on my site. So when I am copying the contents from my word document to the WP Elementor engine, the fonts are a little grayed out in many places and perfect in only a few places. I am not an expert in coding, so I need some advice on how to avoid this part. Kindly find the attached images circles in blue to be perfect ones and circled in Red are[image] the ones causing the issues.

Comment: Word is a mess for this... ...take your content, copy and paste it into a text editor like Sublime and then copy paste it into your WP content editor.  This will strip out all the stupid extras Word adds.

Comment: Thank you let me try that and let you know. Appreciate your Time today.